# Errors while installing react native setup

Tags: react-native

[image]

while running the command as 'run as administrator'

> @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
>   -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object
>   System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
>   && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

I get the above error..Please see the screenshot above.

Comment: please explain what you were trying and what did you achieve

Comment: Installing  chocolatey setup for react native. When I am going to run the command for chocolatey installation using command prompt as 'run as administrator' mode.then I get the above error each time ....please see the screenshot of above image.